# How to fix navigation alignment and add icons to nav bar?

Tags: html, css

I am coding this navigation bar how do I align the items on it like this: And I want to add the icons on the nav like this image any advice?

[image: Screenshot]

```html
<nav>
  <ul class="title-area">
    <!-- float this left -->
    <li>Sunt</li>
    <li>Beatae Vita</li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="nav-items">
    <!-- float this right-->
    <li>Arhieto</li>
    <li>Aperam</li>
    <li>Totam</li>
    <li>Rem</li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow! To improve your experience, read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) an [on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) question. You should also take a look at the [question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) and [how to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). To lean more about how Stack Overflow works, [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: What CSS have you tried writing yourself? And what was the outcome?

Answer (score 3):

You can use [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox#Horizontal_and_vertical_alignment).

```css
nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

li {
  display: inline-block
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul class="title-area">
    <!-- float this left -->
    <li>Sunt</li>
    <li>Beatae Vita</li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="nav-items">
    <!-- float this right-->
    <li>Arhieto</li>
    <li>Aperam</li>
    <li>Totam</li>
    <li>Rem</li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score -1):

`margin-left: auto` magic to the rescue:

```css
nav {
  display: flex;
}

ul.nav-items {
  margin-left: auto;
}

li {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul class="title-area">
    <!-- float this left -->
    <li>Sunt</li>
    <li>Beatae Vita</li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="nav-items">
    <!-- float this right-->
    <li>Arhieto</li>
    <li>Aperam</li>
    <li>Totam</li>
    <li>Rem</li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Explanation: you're telling the margin to take the available space inside the container from the point where the element would originally be rendered onwards.

EDIT: updated the answer to make a better example. Original answer was only concerned with showing the style for the separated halves in the navbar - and assuming the rest would be styled by the OP however they wanted. For anyone left wondering what this accomplishes, with `margin-left: auto` there's no constraint on the number of children the flexbox container has for it to stick to the separation (thus you can even have all the `<li />` inside the same container if semantically they have no reason to be separated).